# Can’t get my (specific) Git workflow to work

Tags: git, workflow

I have a quite specific need, and I can’t get it to work, hence I turn to you, Git and Stack Overflow friends.

I have a server my live site runs on. I wish to update the site using Git. To avoid live testing, I wish to set up a testing environment on the same server, accessible through a subdomain, as if the development folder is a branch of master.

As far as I know, you can’t have branches in different folders, which makes sense. Instead, I cloned the live repository into another folder. From my home computer, I push to a feature branch of the development repository, where I merge it with the “remote” master branch and then push the merges to the live server.

[image: Workflow]

Unfortunately, when I try to push my development master to live master, `git log` does mention the new commits, but the files remain the same. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298499/git-push-not-send-changes-to-remote-git-repository) appears relevant, but no answer solved my problem.

What I do (in chronological order)

1. `~/www $ git init`
2. `~/www $ git touch file.txt` (and fill it)
3. `~/www $ git add .`
4. `~/www $ git commit -m "Initial commit"`
5. `~/dev $ git clone ~/www .`
6. Make some changes to `~/dev/file.txt`
7. `~/dev $ git add .`
8. `~/dev $ git commit -m "Dev commit"`
9. `~/dev $ git push`

When inspecting `~/www/file.txt`, nothing has changed :(

A `git log` command in `~/www` (the original repository) *does* show the commit:

```
commit 677fed22f18d2a98c9b03fc4256c2ef78bd68e8d
Author: Tim Severien <tim********@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 14 16:36:38 2015 +0100

    Dev commit

commit 7dd9b40dd29a63ba8ea7d647b4afd575f2376659
Author: Tim Severien <tim********@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 14 16:35:39 2015 +0100

    Initial commit
```

---

1. **Why doesn’t my live repository change?**
2. **Do you have better ideas for this kind of workflow?**

Comment: You're likely to scare away a good few potential answerers by addressing them as "gods". Most of us are mere *demigods*, at best `:)` More seriously, I'm afraid your problem is going to be difficult to diagnose without more information. Could you edit it and add the sequence of commands that your typical workflow consists in?

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for your comment! Changed “gods” to “friends” to make the question more accessible ;) Also, I added a step-by-step description of what I do :)

Comment: `git status` in `~` gives me a fatal error, saying it’s not a repository. If you meant `~/www`, it tells me there are some changes that are yet to be committed, which seems odd.

Comment: @Jubobs Nothing unexpected. Counting objects, writing objects, unpacking projects, all 100% done. Trying another push tells me everything is up-to-date. `git remote -v` tells me `origin /path/to/www (fetch)
origin /path/to/www (push)` All seems fine :(

Comment: Probably relevant: I set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `ignore`.

Comment: Pushing to the checked out branch in a non-bare repository is generally not what you want to do

Comment: @AndrewC Probably not, but I’m having difficulties to find a better way, hence the question “Do you have better ideas for this kind of workflow?” Feel free to suggest ideas :)

Comment: You should be able to find some good articles searching on "git receive hook deploy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `HEAD` is out of sync with the index and the working tree

By setting `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `ignore` in the repository living in `~/www`, you're allowing pushes to its checked-out branch (`master`, here), which brings the `HEAD` out of sync with the index and the working tree.

This phenomenon is explained in the [`git-config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `receive.denyCurrentBranch`
>
> If set to `true` or `"refuse"`, `git-receive-pack` will deny a ref update to
>   the currently checked out branch of a non-bare repository. *Such a push
>   is potentially dangerous because it brings the HEAD out of sync with
>   the index and working tree.* [...] If set to `false` or
>   `"ignore"`, allow such pushes with no message. [...]

(my emphasis)

Try running

```sh
$ git diff
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index ce01362..e69de29 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-hello
```

in `~/www`. Note that `git diff` outputs nothing, proving that the working tree and the index are in sync, whereas `git diff --cached` shows a difference between `HEAD` and the index.

#### What you're doing wrong

As pointed out by Andrew C in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516978/can-t-get-my-specific-git-workflow-to-work/28517497#comment45351834_28516978),

> Pushing to the checked out branch in a non-bare repository is generally not what you want to do

... for the reason discussed above.

#### What you should do

You should rethink your workflow and avoid that. The question [Push to a non-bare Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/push-to-a-non-bare-git-repository) and its answers should be relevant, here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unusual to push to a non bare repo. Not that it can't work, but, as you're noticing, it can be a bit subtle. Moreover, doing this, you have the full history of your project, on your web server. It's not an issue in itself, but it seems it's wasting space needlessly.

What about adding to your repo a `deploy.sh` script instead? It could be for instance as simple as

```
cp -r . ~/www
```

A first advantage is that it would solve your push issues. An other advantage is that you could make it evolve, as you'll discover other needs. For instance, a second iteration could look like

```
INITIAL_SHA1=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
SHA1_TO_DEPLOY=$1
DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT=$2

git checkout $SHA1_TO_DEPLOY
if ! ./runTests.sh; then
  echo Commit $SHA1_TO_DEPLOY is corrupted. Won't deploy it
else
  cp -r . $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT
fi
git checkout $INITIAL_SHA1
```

Of course, this is not a direct answer to your question, however I believe it might answer your needs.