# git push not updating remote git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I'm working on some file in my local git repository and want to send the changes to the an existing remote git repository from which the local was cloned via https. I know you're not suppose to update a not bare-repository, so I created a branch to push the changes.
Here is what I've done, which isn't working:

created my `git init` - local
`git add -A // added all files`
`git commit -m "first commit"`
`git remote add origin [https://github.com/...]`
`git push -u origin master`

This I understand, it pushed to github - hooray!

Now I want to update the GitHub repository.
First I thought you could just do, after `git add *` & `git commit -m "message"`, `git push origin master`, but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298499/git-push-not-send-changes-to-remote-git-repository), I realized you should push to a repository that is not bare.
So, I created a branch!  `git checkout -b new-branch`.
I followed the same sets as above, `git add  *`, `git commit -m "message"`, `git push origin new-branch`..."Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'."
Great!

So, I want to merge these branches, I switch to the master branch, and do a `git pull` and then `git push origin master`.
I get the message every up-up-to-date. But when I check the remote repo, nothing has updated!
Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   .bowerrc
new file:   bower.json
modified:   index.html
new file:   public/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min/.bower.json
new file:   public/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min/index.js
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, in regard of the `git status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> realized you should push to a repository that is not bare.

No, you should push to a bare repo, not a non-bare repo.

And all GitHub repo are bare anyway, so pushing is not tied to creating a branch.

According to your git status, you are still on the branch `master`, with files already added to the index.
Simply commit and push. No need for a new branch.

Comment: thank you so much! I wasn't adding the git commit...lesson learned! Thanks again!