# Git Push Not Updating the Code

Tags: git, bash, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am updating the code on my remote repository.
Due to some reason, the updates are not getting reflected.

```
git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '*********/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 421 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Already on 'master'
remote: M       app/Http/routes.php
To ssh://ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/***************
   ce2cc5b..8149f07  master -> master
```

I am not getting what "remote: M" is.

Please guide me. I have to make the release as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -vv` ?

Comment: I am getting the following output for git remote -vv:-   origin  ssh://root@ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/*************** (fetch)
origin  ssh://root@ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/*************** (push)

Comment: I guess `remote: M` means Modified but not sure.
Did you look git history to see if it his clean. What gives `git status` ? Are you alone to work on this repository ?

Comment: Git status is giving "nothing to commit, working tree clean". And currently I am alone working on this repository..

Comment: I guess you already did but try a git pull. What do you mean by "reflected" ? What did you expect ?

Comment: I want the changes from local repository to be made into remote repository. Actually, I am able push the code to the remote empty repository for the first time but when I am again updating the code, I can't see the changes.

Comment: Maybe you are pushing to a non-bare repository? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298499/git-push-not-send-changes-to-remote-git-repository

Comment: No sir... Its a bare repository. I am able to push once in an empty repository. But when I am again pushing the changes, its not getting updated. I have created a hook post-receive on the remote repository as given below "#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=********************
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout master
"

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that when you run `git push` (or, for that matter, `git fetch`), there are *two* Gits and *two* repositories involved in the process.  One is "your" Git and "your" repository, and the other is the remote's Git and its repository.  (The repository at the remote may belong to you as well, but just think of it as some *other* person, taking requests from you, over an Internet-phone-call.)

Messages printed *without* `remote:` in front of them are coming from *your* Git.  Messages printed *with* `remote:` in front are coming from the remote.  They're not coming directly from the other Git—the two Gits have their Internet-phone arrangement set up so that they talk directly and know what each other is saying—but rather, from something *run by* the other Git.  When the other Git runs things—such as hooks—and those things print *their* own messages, *their* Git copies those messages across to your Git, saying to your Git: "I don't know what this means, but the hook printed this, and it might be important, so why don't you show this to the only human being available in ths whole process, i.e., the person doing the `git push`?"  And your Git does: it prints `remote: whatever` to indicate that something the *other* Git ran printed *`whatever`*.

---

Now, in your setup, you have a *deployment script* set up on the other system.  That's your post-receive hook.  A post-receive hook can do many things, but your particular script is intended as a deployment mechanism.  You put approximate contents of this script up in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698978/git-push-not-updating-the-code#comment70595089_41698978), but here it is better-formatted (comments do not support formatting):

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=********************
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout master
```

What this script does is make the otherwise bare repository—the one on the remote—act as a non-bare repository: the *work tree* is specified through `GIT_WORK_TREE`.  (Incidentally, you could make this a one line script, instead of three lines: `git --work-tree=... checkout master`.  There's no particular reason to prefer either form here other than personal taste, though.)

What kind of output does `git checkout` sometimes print?  Well, let's try it:

```
$ git checkout master
M       wt-status.c
Already on 'master'
```

What did you see in your output, prefixed with `remote:`?

> ```
> remote: Already on 'master'
> remote: M       app/Http/routes.php
> ```

Conclusion: this is almost certainly coming from the `git checkout` command your deployment script runs.  (The order of the two lines has changed, but they're still from the `git checkout`.)

When *does* `git checkout` print this kind of message?  Git's [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) is a bit thin here, but:

> To prepare for working on `<branch>`, switch to it by updating the
>    index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at
>    the branch. **Local modifications to the files in the working tree
>    are kept**, so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.

Thus, this occurs when the index and/or work-tree are modified, but those local modifications can be kept.  (See [Git - checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for details.)

This means that your (remote) work-tree has some change made to file `app/Http/routes.php`, with respect to the `HEAD` commit.<sup>1</sup>  When you, with your Git, push to the remote, with its Git, the remote Git runs the deployment script.  When the deployment script uses your undisclosed work-tree along with the bare repository to make it act like a non-bare repository, and the other Git's deployment script runs `git checkout`, *that* checkout "keeps the (local-to-remote-work-tree) modification", but prints that `M` line.

Since the modification being kept is *on* the remote, the only way to deal with it is to *go to* the remote (e.g., ssh in) so that you can work locally there.  Then, investigate why that work-tree is modified: Who made this change?  Why?  What does it do?  Should it be in the repository?  Should it be done some other way?  Do you need to modify the deployment script?  *I* cannot answer any of these questions for you; *you* must decide how to make this all work.

---

<sup>1</sup>Slightly complicating the picture, these could be in the remote's *index*.  This index is in fact the *bare repository's* index, because `git --work-tree=... checkout` uses the (single) index from the repository, even though that index reflects the work-tree.  Chances are, however, that the change is only in the deployment work-tree over on the remote.

Comment: Thank You sir.... Finally I got to know from where remote: M is getting displayed. I just modified the hook post-receive as "GIT_WORK_TREE=********************
export GIT_WORK_TREE git checkout -f master" and now every thing is working fine... Thanks a lot every one...